# $G = \mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ surjective map and kernel isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Let $G = \mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$, written additively. For all $n > 0$ how come $p_n(x) = nx$ is a surjective homomorphism from $G \rightarrow G$ and how come the kernel of $p_n(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$? I know that once the above are true that we can conclude that $G$ is isomorphic to a proper quotient of itself, but I can not figure out why the above two are true.

Comment: Surjectivity is easy: if $y\in\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ has representative $q\in\Bbb Q$, then the coset $x$ containing $\frac{q}{n}$ satisfies $nx=y$.

Comment: ah awesome that makes sense, I still am having trouble understanding the kernel part

Comment: You can compute the kernel explicitly. Which cosets are mapped to "zero" in this quotient group?

Comment: Put $\alpha_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Notice that $\ker(p_n)=\langle \overline{\alpha_n}\rangle$, and there is an isomorphisms between $\ker(p_n)$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ sending $\overline{\alpha_n}$ to $1$.

Comment: @wore, would it send to 1 or 0?

Comment: @PhilKing I was thinking about the map $\phi:\ker(p_n)\to \mathbb{Z}_n$ sending $\overline{\alpha_n}$ (which is the generator of $\ker(p_n)$) to the element 1 ($\mod n$), which is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Answer (score 2):

An easy proof results from the *snake lemma*: you have a commutative diagram of short exact sequences:
\begin{alignat*}{3}\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}
0\longrightarrow &\mathbf Z\longrightarrow &&\mathbf Q\longrightarrow &&\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z\longrightarrow 0\\
m_\mathbf Z &{\downarrow} &m_\mathbf Q&\downarrow  & &\downarrow m_{\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z}\\
0\longrightarrow &\mathbf Z\longrightarrow &&\mathbf Q\longrightarrow &&\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z\longrightarrow 0
\end{alignat*}
in which the vertical maps are multiplication by $n$. The snake lemma assets we have an exact sequence
$$0\to \ker m_\mathbf Z\to \ker m_\mathbf Q\to\ker m_{\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z}\xrightarrow{\delta} \coker m_\mathbf Z\to  \coker m_\mathbf Q\to\coker m_{\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z}\to 0 $$
Now $\ker m_\mathbf Z= \ker m_\mathbf Q=0$ and $ \coker m_\mathbf Q=0$, since we're in a field. So $\coker m_{\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z}=0$, which means multiplication by $n$ in $\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ is surjective, and  this exact sequence reduces to 
$$0\to\ker m_{\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z}\xrightarrow{\delta} \coker m_\mathbf Z\to 0$$ 
and this means $\delta$ is an isomorphism from $\ker m_{\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z}$ onto $\coker m_\mathbf Z=\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$.